# My PageMethods never gets reached in .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've tried everything and nothing works. The PageMethods never gets reached, but everything before that call is fine. Could it be something in the code-behind? I'm suspecting that I'm doing something wrong with the project overall. Could it be something that I have to put in the page master?

```
public class GetElements
    {
        [ScriptMethod, WebMethod]
        public static string[] getTargets()
        {
            //List<string> targetList = new List<string>();
            string[] targetList = new string[2];
            targetList[0] = "poo";
            targetList[1] = "bar";
            foreach (Target t in PbcXml.oDeserialized.oTargetList)
            {
            }
            return targetList;
        }
    }
```

javascript:

```
var a = new Array();
getTarget();
function getTarget() {
    PageMethods.getTargets(OnSuccessLoad);
    return false;
}
function OnSuccessLoad(response) {
    for (var v in response) {
        //a.push(v);
        alert(v);
    }
}
```

aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do exactly with this method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you only need the `WebMethod` attribute on your static method... been a while since I did a PageMethod. Also, you have the page method defined on some other class that is not a WebForms page. You need to define it on the ASP.NET WebForms page that will call it. I think this is the issue.

If it is still not working after trying the above, load the Javascript console of your browser to see the Javascript errors you are getting and also run a free tool like Fiddler, http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, to see what's going on in terms of web requests if there are no JS errors.

Hope that helps.